# finding the formula to a given table of values

Tags: functions

I created a spreadsheet that i filled with values i got from a game. The values may be rounded, but they were calculated, so there has to be a formula behind.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XsoDsRbWwFdveM80rJVDHTYD0PzMzYHG-S-5coTf9Zw/edit?usp=sharing

How do i get to the formula of the first table on the second sheet (Heat MGMT)?

The values are limited to be not greater than 2. They used to be higher, but the game won't go further than 2. The other tables and charts were some experiments to find a solution myself, but i was not successful.

Cells A3:A28 (Column A) are holding the values for HPS, Cells B2:L1 (Row 1) are holding the values for HDPS. These values are given and can be floating point values. I picked absolute values to make it easier finding equalities.

The formula i'm looking for, is to calculate the values of B3:L28 (HMGMT). One for calculating them all.
The values listed there are take from the game as a reference. The calculated values should match them.

The two charts to the right are to visualize the values. The other two "tables" along with their charts, are for finding the equalities.

I also don't know wich tags are appropriate, so please be so kind and correct me.

I posted this Question first on [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194655/finding-the-formula-to-a-given-table-of-values?noredirect=1#comment484696_194655), but was asked to post it here.

Comment: Do you want to find a formula for each set of HPS? Do you have an idea of formula? For example, since your tag is polynomial, do you know that they should be polynomial? If so, I suggest you do a least square fitting on each one of them.

Comment: Make it easier on the people who you're expecting to get help from. Add the relevant piece of information ("the first table on the second sheet" as you call it) - into this question. Explain what part of the table you want as a formula. There seem to be many possible formulas for different columns in it. Explain briefly what you want. For example, "is there a formula that gives the values of column B as a function of the corresponding values of column A?".

Comment: I just added some more informations, hope that clarifies things @barakmanos

Comment: Since you assume that the values are calculated but might have been rounded, it doesn't really make sense to search a function that does an exact match for all values in the table (a polynomial with high enough degree can be found, but it is unlikely that it'll behave "properly" between two given points). It'll be better to search for a function that gives a good approximation. If the input values can be negative, it would be interesting to know how the results vary. The answer below gives a suggestion which doesn't work in case of negative input.

Comment: What is going on in G33 and I33???

Comment: @JpMcCarthy these are just dummy formulas that i created from the values, the lower charts gave me. Thought they could lead me to the answer, if combined.